# The convergence of an improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration

Let us find all values of $\alpha$ such that the following improper integral converges:

$$I(\alpha):=\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{ e^{\dot{\imath}(x^2-2x)}}{x^{\alpha}}\,dx$$.

When $\alpha>1$,  $I(\alpha)$ is absolutely convergent.

When $-1<\alpha\leq 1$, the integral converges 
by the Dirichlet test, since in that case:

$$I(\alpha):=c+e^{-\dot{\imath}}\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{ e^{\dot{\imath}(x-1)^{2}}}{x^{\alpha}}\,dx$$
where 
$$c=\int_{1}^{2} \frac{ e^{\dot{\imath}(x-1)^{2}}}{x^{\alpha}}\,dx,$$ and changing variables implies

$$\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{ e^{\dot{\imath}(x-1)^{2}}}{x^{\alpha}}\,dx=
\frac{1}{2}\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{ e^{\dot{\imath}(x-1)^{2}}2(x-1)}{x^{\alpha}(x-1)}\,dx\\
=\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{ e^{\dot{\imath}y}}{(\sqrt{y}+1)^{\alpha}\sqrt{y}}\,dy$$
which converges by the Dirichlet test.
Notice that $\frac{1}{(\sqrt{y}+1)^{\alpha}\sqrt{y}}\rightarrow 0$
when $y\rightarrow \infty$ for all $\alpha>-1$.

When $\alpha=-1$, 
$$I(-1)=\frac{e^{-\dot{\imath}}}{2}\left(\int_{1}^{\infty}2(x-1) e^{\dot{\imath}(x-1)^{2}}dx+2\int_{1}^{\infty} e^{\dot{\imath}(x-1)^{2}}dx \right)$$

The second integral converges by the Dirichlet test as before ($\alpha=0$ here).
 But, the first integral $\int_{1}^{\infty}2(x-1) e^{\dot{\imath}(x-1)^{2}}dx=
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{\dot{\imath}x}dx$ which diverges.

If $\alpha<-1$ we can show that $I(\alpha)$ diverges in a fashion similar to the case $\alpha=-1$; we integrate by parts as many times as necessary we get the divergent integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{\dot{\imath}x}dx$ 
plus other integrals that converge by the Dirichlet test.

I would appreciate it if any expert reviewed my solution.

Thanks a lot.